# httpUrlConnection set request header

Tags: url, header, web-crawler, httpurlconnection

i am recently starting learning to write web crawler by refering to other people's code ,one part of the code is about downloading the http url page of the target website,so it used **HttpUrlConnection** module,however i can't understand the follwing  code after trying so hard，can anyone **provide some fundamental reference material for me to understand this or just explain to me** ?

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", encoding);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setConnectTimeout( 100000 );
connection.setReadTimeout( 100000 );
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
```

**first**,i don't know why **connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()** is writting like this ,usually we write **HttpURLConnection connection=new HttpURLConnection()**,**i mean we create an object by this way**;
**next** i mean i know those set syntax ,it is all about setting the header of the client request,but i just don't know what these set sytaxes are used for ? why they are setted to these values instead of other values?

i read the related chapter of Core Java Volume 2,but it cannot answer my question,i googled a lot ,but just cannot find explanation about these set syntaxes,any help will be appreciated,thanks~

Answer (score 0):

The method `openConnection` of class `URL` in Java returns an `URLConnection` which could be cast to `HttpURLConnection` in advance. You need it in order to set the other required fields of an HTTP request, for example setting the request method (GET, PUT, POST). This is the most important field of your request. You should decide according to what you are requesting and from where you are requesting. read and connection timeout values you can play around with, usually used in case when request does not return a response due to internet connection problems on either server side or client side. Finally, commonly used `setRequestProperty` method sets the headers for your request.

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

is widely used. In order to determine the content type of the respose, call `getHeaderField` first:

```
String contentType = con.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
```

Note: If your request requires additional parameters, you should put them in a map and output to your request.

Comment: thanks@golyadkin,that's very clear explanation,i also  find this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUPDGbnpSjw,this help me understand how the client and web server communicate with each other and the underlying theory of http protocol at the layman's level,just for someone else reference